# Jquery Autocomplete doesn't work

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, autocomplete, jquery-autocomplete

i'm trying to add an autocomplete to an input box (i'm in asp.net/vb.net project) with the autocomplete source from a database.
So i've created a webservice and i did an ajax call:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {

                $('#modelloInput').autocomplete({

                    source: function (request, response) {
                        $.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                            url: "WebServices/AutocompleteWS.asmx/getTuttiIModelli",
                            data: "{'prefix':'" + request.term + "'}",
                            dataType: "json",
                            async: true,
                            success: function (data) {
                                response(data.d);
                            },
                            error: function (result) {
                                //alert("Error");
                            }
                        });
                    }

                });
            }); 
</script>

<input type=text  id="modelloInput" />
```

Now when i run the application and i write something in the inputbox i got the entire list in the autocomplete box.
I can write everything but i get always the entire list of elements.

Why?

Comment: can you paste your web service code also?

Comment: Is the URL correct? The code will definitely post if it is.

Comment: @JalpeshVadgama i can do this but the call to the webservice works good because i get in the response exactly what i want, but the autocomplete don't do the filter base on what i'm writing

Comment: @JohnReid the URL is correct because i don't get error from chrome/firefox console

Comment: Does it filters the list and change only parts that are required? For example there three names Jalpesh,Vishal and Tushar and you type Tu your server side code should only return tushar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there must be some issue in your web-service code,

you can use this basic code for autoComplete,

```
$( "input.suggest-user" ).autocomplete({
  source: function( request, response ) {

    $.ajax({
        dataType: "json",
        type : 'Get',
        url: 'yourURL',
        success: function(data) {
          $('input.suggest-user').removeClass('ui-autocomplete-loading');  // hide loading image

        response( $.map( data, function(item) {
            // your operation on data
        }));
      },
      error: function(data) {
          $('input.suggest-user').removeClass('ui-autocomplete-loading');  
      }
    });
  },
  minLength: 3,
  open: function() {

  },
  close: function() {

  },
  focus:function(event,ui) {

  },
  select: function( event, ui ) {

  }
});
```

OR

```
$("#id").autocomplete(
{
search: function () {},
source: function (request, response)
{
    $.ajax(
    {
        url: ,
        dataType: "json",
        data:
        {
            term: request.term,
        },
        success: function (data)
        {
            response(data);
        }
    });
},
minLength: 2,
select: function (event, ui)
{
    var test = ui.item ? ui.item.id : 0;
    if (test > 0)
    {}
}
});
```